# Create Custom Post type that uses Page.php template

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

I am creating a plugin that registers a custom post type, and I want it to be displayed using the theme's page.php template, rather than the post.php. I set the `hierarchical` flag when I register it, but the post.php template is still called.

Way, way down inside wp-includes/post.php, where it appears to decide which template to use, is the code:

```
if ( ! empty( $postarr['page_template'] ) && 'page' == $data['post_type'] ) {
    $post->page_template = $postarr['page_template'];
    $page_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates( $post );
    ...
```

which makes me think that the post template is used unless `post_type` is exactly `'page'`.

I don't want to define a template of my own, because I want to work with any theme. I just want to tell WordPress which of the current theme's templates to use.

There's an action hook, called `get_template_part_{$slug}` that might do the trick, but I'm not sure what it expects, and the documentation for that one is unusually spotty.

Comment: And no sooner do I post that than I find the 'single_template' filter hook. Now if I can figure out how to return the page template for the current theme, I'm on my way.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `template_include` and then let WordPress search for a page template in all valid templates like `page.php`, `index.php` and even files from a parent theme.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    return is_singular( [ 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' ] ) ? get_page_template() : $template;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks really good. I'm just waiting for a free moment to try it out.

Comment: One of the themes I work with uses get_template_part() to load the template for that part of the page; when I call get_page_template() in that context I don't get anything back. I've got a hack in place to filter `request`, which then causes my type to return true for is_page(), but it makes me a little nervous.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly it. You should be able to use something like this, replacing the `your_post_type`:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'your_post_type') {
        $single_template = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/page.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

Comment: That was all well and good and I was excited until I noticed that the other theme I'm testing on doesn't have a page.php, but instead uses content-page.php, presumably called by `get_template_part` somewhere (maybe the default page.php?). So I can't count on `page.php` being in the theme directory. Is there a way to ask Wordpress "if you were to render a page right now, what template would you use?"

Comment: There's no way that your other theme can *only* be using content-page.php.  It must be using page.php, which then includes content-page.php.

Comment: Curious. There is no `page.php` file in the theme's directory, and no template listed in the styles.css header, which I take to mean it's not a child theme that uses another theme's `page.php`. Indeed, all the other themes have a page.php file. I assume there's some global Wordpress fallback, but I can't find it.

Comment: According to the template hierarchy, if page.php doesn't exist, then it may use singular.php or index.php

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Comment: Turns out it has custom loop in its index.php that calls a function that renders the stuff. Yarg. So... back to figuring out how to make is_singular() be false and is_page() be true, I guess.